# OrientDB -Order by FIELD not working

Tags: orientdb

I want to order the table by the id's given within "IN Clause"

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN [1,2,3,4] ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,2,1,4);

But i am getting error as response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, OrientDB does not support this in current release. Please open an issue on the official issue tracker, we'll consider it for next releases.